# Select MAX com o campo em Unix TimeStamp

Tags: sql-server, timestamp

Eu tenho um banco de dados no qual as tabelas possuem uma coluna TimeStamp (nome da coluna) que é do tipo int, onde eu guardo o valor no formato de Unix TimeStamp. Estou tentando dar um select na data mais recente. Contudo não sei se é possivel fazer esta filtragem com o valor no formato de Unix TimeStamp, ou se é necessario fazer a converção para DateTime.

Estou tentando desta forma :

```
SELECT MAX (TimeStamp)
```

Até agora tem dado certo, contudo tenho medo dos resultados terem sido coincidência. Gostaria de saber se posso fazer este select com os valores no formato Unix TimeStamp, e ele me retornar de fato a data mais atual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Levi, como trata-se de um campo int, o MAX vai te atender perfeitamente, pode continuar utilizando dessa forma.

Answer (score 0):

Levi, no SQL Server o tipo de dados TIMESTAMP não guarda data/hora, pois ele é um contador do banco de dados e que é incrementado para cada operação de inserção ou atualização executada em uma tabela.

Detalhes em [ROWVERSION](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql).

Comment: No caso TimeStamp é o nome da coluna, editei isto na pergunta pois estava dando a entender que o campo era um TimeStamp.

Comment: @Levi Ok. Entendido.